# Помогите разобраться в api [JSON]

Tags: java, android, json, http

Мне нужно использовать вот это [api](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geosearch/concepts/about-docpage/):

Я написал вот такой код:

```
public class JsonResponse {

HttpURLConnection urlConnection ;
BufferedReader reader ;
String resultJson ;
String strJson;

private String phone;
private String address;
private String name;

public String get() {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=Отель&lang=ru_RU&apikey=тут мой Api key");

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        resultJson = buffer.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultJson;}



protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {

  onPostExecute(strJson);




    JSONObject dataJsonObj;
    String Name;

    try {
        dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
        JSONArray objects = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("features");
        JSONObject meta = objects.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt("CompanyMetaData"));

        JSONObject phones = meta.getJSONObject("CompanyMetaData.Phones");
        String name = meta.getString("name");


        String address = meta.getString("address");


        String phone = phones.getString("formatted");




    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getStrJson() {
    return strJson;
}
}
```

**Вызов в main activity:**

```
JsonResponse json = new JsonResponse();
    Log.d(TAG,"Json:" + json.getStrJson() );
    Log.d(TAG,"JsonName:" + json.getName() );
    Log.d(TAG,"JsonPhone:" + json.getPhone() );
    Log.d(TAG,"JsonAddress:" + json.getAddress() );
```

**В логах null.**

Comment: Вы создали экземпляр класса, но не вызвали нужный метод. Вот ничего и не сделалось и всё `null`. И запрос в сеть надо из не-UI потока делать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Не понимаю 
>И запрос в сеть надо из не-UI потока делать.

Comment: Используйте Thread, AsynkTask, IntentService etc. При попытке запроса в сеть из основного потока приложение упадёт.

Comment: Не очень похоже что вы этот код писали, раз не вызвав `get()` хотите видеть значения :)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант А. Многопоточность: в таком случае метод JsonResponse#get() переписываем в run, сам класс или наследуем от Thread или подключаем интерфейс Runnable. А в main activity уже запускаем данный поток. После завершения выполнения, можно с помощью Handler уведомлять главный поток.Вот тут маленько: [линк](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/thread.php).

Вариант B. AsyncTask. Вот материал: [линк](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php).

Ну и на хабре: [хаб](https://habrahabr.ru/post/124484/).